# different between call instruction when calling main() and normal function for assembly language

Tags: c++, assembly, callstack

I am studying asm language by compiling c source code into asm langugae.
I ready known the `call` instruction is equivalent of

```
push ret_address
jmp my_func
```

But it seem that calling a main function is quite different from calling a noraml function.
For example:

```
// c source code. ret is a normal function.
long ret(long i)
{
    return i++;
}

int main()
{
    long i=0;
    i = ret(i);
    return i;
}
```

After compiled into asm, the asm code for `main` and `ret` function are:

```
Dump of assembler code for function main():
   0x0000000100401096 <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x0000000100401097 <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x000000010040109a <+4>: sub    $0x30,%rsp
   0x000000010040109e <+8>: callq  0x100401160 <__main>
=> 0x00000001004010a3 <+13>:    movq   $0x0,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x00000001004010ab <+21>:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
   0x00000001004010af <+25>:    mov    %rax,%rcx
   0x00000001004010b2 <+28>:    callq  0x100401080 <ret(long)>
   0x00000001004010b7 <+33>:    mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x00000001004010bb <+37>:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
   0x00000001004010bf <+41>:    add    $0x30,%rsp
   0x00000001004010c3 <+45>:    pop    %rbp
   0x00000001004010c4 <+46>:    retq
```

```
Dump of assembler code for function ret(long):
   0x0000000100401080 <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x0000000100401081 <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000100401084 <+4>: mov    %rcx,0x10(%rbp)
=> 0x0000000100401088 <+8>: mov    0x10(%rbp),%rax
   0x000000010040108c <+12>:    lea    0x1(%rax),%rdx
   0x0000000100401090 <+16>:    mov    %rdx,0x10(%rbp)
   0x0000000100401094 <+20>:    pop    %rbp
   0x0000000100401095 <+21>:    retq
```

When calling `main()`, three instructions `push   %rbp`, `mov    %rsp,%rbp`,`sub    $0x30,%rsp` has already be executed.
Thus the call instruction will push the previous instruction stored in `rip` register into the position (-$0x30 + %rsp), as `sub    $0x30,%rsp` has already exectuted. This is not how function calling stack works.

When calling `ret()`, these three instructions are executed after call instruction, which is quite normal.

So is there something special for calling `main()`? Why the asm code behaviors differently?

Comment: You're looking at the code that implements main, not the code for *calling* main (in CRT startup).  Also, you're looking at where the debug info (generated by the compiler) tells GDB to set a breakpoint after the prologue, which for `main` in MinGW and/or cygwin includes calling an init function.  It's nothing special about *calling* main, it's that MinGW makes `main` itself special.  If you actually set a breakpoint on the symbol address, like `b *0x0000000100401080`, GDB would stop there, and you could single-step instructions with `stepi` (`si`) or `nexti` (`ni`).

Comment: Also, `ret()` seems a poor choice of name for experiments; it's easy to confuse with a call that goes directly a a `ret` instruction (like you'd get if you compiled with optimization, for an empty function other than `main`: https://godbolt.org/z/8j8WrMjY5)

Comment: @PeterCordes I almost get your point. The webstie is very helpful. Thanks.